# How to get a space character in a file in c++ without getline

Tags: c++, file

I was using c++ and reading a file character by character. I did that using >> operator. But when space comes up it will display wrong because in that case it won't take that input. So, how can I get a space character and that too without using getline.

Comment: What is wrong with `getline`?

Comment: @Andrey: If you're reading character by character, then `getline()` adds an unnecessary copy (and probably an unnecessary dynamic memory allocation if you use the `std::string` version).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [std::istreambuf_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("file.txt");

    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> it(file), end;

    for (; it != end; ++it) {
        std::cout << *it;
    }
}
```

You'll get better performance if you open the file in binary mode, read it whole at once in a buffer and then work on that:

```
 #include <vector>
 #include <fstream>

 int main()
 {
      std::ifstream file("file.txt", std::ios::binary);
      file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);  // seek to the end
      std::streamsize size = file.tellg();  // get the position (file size)
      file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);  // seek back to the beginning

      std::vector<char> buffer(size);
      file.read(&buffer[0], size);

      // do the work on vector
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using `istream& get ( char& c );` ? That reads a single character at a time. The following example shows how:

```
char c;
while ( cin.get(c) )
{
    cout << "> " << c << endl;
}
```

Running it gives:

```
echo "hello world" | ./sing_in 
> h
> e
> l
> l
> o
>  
> w
> o
> r
> l
> d
>
```

Without further clues as to what you're doing I can't really say if it will help you and I don't understand your reticence to use `getline`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a file by character, don't use `>>`.

```
ifstream File ("file.txt");
char Buffer[ARBITRARY_SIZE];
File.read(Buffer, ARBITRARY_SIZE);
```

Then, you can just parse the buffer. It's much faster. It will be also faster than `.get()`. You can run all normal string operations on the Buffer (convert it to stringstream, for example). Then, all the operations will be done in memory.

Answer (score 0):

- you can use `istream.get(char&)`, `istream.get()`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/get/

or

- from the `<iomanip>` header - `noskipws`: see the example at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/noskipws/